# How to Register MediatR in .NET 6 Web API where MediatR UsecCses are in separate project

Tags: .net-6.0, webapi, mediatr

I am working on C# Web API 6.0 project with MediatR. Since I am following clean architecture, I have separate project for Web API and Application. I have useCases in Application project with Queries, Commands and handler.

I have register MediatR to WebApplicationBuilder with reference of class 'ApplicationAssembly'. The 'ApplicationAssembly' class is inside Application project.

`API Service Contrainer`

```
public static class ServicesConfigurator
{
    public static void Configure(WebApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddControllers();
   
        builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
   
        builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

        builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(ApplicationAssembly));

        builder.Services.AddMediatR(typeof(ApplicationAssembly).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
      
  }
```

The above code don't work the way I register MediatR

```
 Exception thrown: 'System.AggregateException' in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll
```

if I changed to

```
builder.Services.AddMediatR(typeof(Program));
```

then I get following error

```
One or more errors occurred. (Error constructing handler for request of type MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[SalaryTracker.Application.UseCases.User.Queries.GetUser, SalaryTracker.Application.WrapperDTOs.UserWrapperDataView]. Register your handlers with the container. See the samples in GitHub for examples.)
```

Comment: Not sure if this is it, but it should be typeof(ApplicationAssembly).Assembly (without the GetTypeInfo). In any case, the AggregateException is just a wrapper around the actual exception(s) that are being thrown. You need to look at the InnerExceptions collection of the AggregateException to know what really happened. With that information, you might be able to solve the issue.